# Can I post with a form JSON data to HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php, html, json, post

I am creating a web interface for code that usually runs from android -

I send json data and get the data by the following:

```
$json = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,true);
```

Is there a way for my to post this data via HTML? Something like?

```
<form action="http://<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>/index.php/search" method="POSTRAW" >

    <input type="hidden" value="JSONSTRING">
    <input type="submit" value="Back">
    </form>
```

Comment: please revise your post, its not clear like this

Comment: sorry formatting didn't come through

Comment: You should be using `php://input` instead. Also, `"Warning:
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.6.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged."` (*Source: [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)*)

Comment: You can do it with ajax, but not with a html form post.

Comment: do u have an example with ajax? I'm down

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd post it properly to an endpoint as `$_POST` data. If this is the only option you have to access the data, you should be using `php://input` instead:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data,true);
```

It won't be as simple as that though, you won't be seeing the post data like you normally do (associative array). You're actually going to receive the raw post string that looks similar to this:

```
variable1=something&variable2=something_else...
```

So you'll need to account for that.
<sup>[*Source*](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php#112032)</sup>